# ¿Cómo llenar varios Select (agregados con JavaScript) con la misma información? Solo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, select

Necesito llenar varios `Select` con la misma información, pero solo me la muestra en el primer `Select` y no en los que se van agregando. No se como resolverlo. Usé `document.getElementsByName` porque con `document.getElementById`  no se puede ya que el ID debe ser único. Aquí les muestro mi código, **soy nuevo programando,** agradezco mucho su ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

[image: el botón agregar crean nuevos select]

Al dar al botón agregar se crean nuevos  `select`  donde debería cargar la información también pero no sale.

**HTML**

```
<h4>REALIZAR PEDIDOS</h4>

<div class="caja-pedidos">
   <div class="label-pedidos">
       <label id="label-tipoP">TIPO</label>
       <label id="label-pedido">PEDIDO</label>
       <label id="label-precio">PRECIO</label>
       <label id="label-cantidad">CANT</label>
   </div>
   <div class="realizar-pedidos" id="realizarPedidos">
       <div class="realizar-pedidos">
           <select id="tipo-pedido" class="form-select" name="tipo-pedido">
               <option></option>
           </select>
           <select id="pedido" class="form-select">
               <option> </option>
           </select>
           <input id="precio-pedido" readonly placeholder="$" class="form-control">
           <input type="number" id="cant-pedido" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"> 
       </div>
   </div>
                   

   <!-- <label id="observacion">OBSERVACIONES</label> -->
<div class="text-area">
<textarea id="obser-pedido" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES" class="form-control"></textarea>
   </div>
       <div class="btn-agregar22">
<button type="button" class="btn-agregar" id="btn-editar" onclick="agregarNuevo()"><i class="bi bi-plus-square-fill"></i> Agregar </button>
   </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//LLENAR EL PRIMER SELECT... 

  function myOnLoad() {
    cargarSelect()
   }

  function cargarSelect(){
    let menuTiposPlatos = ["Perros", "Hamburguesas", "Pizzas",  ]

    agregarOpciones("tipo-pedido", menuTiposPlatos);
  }
  function agregarOpciones(domElement, menuTiposPlatos) {
    var select = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
   
    for (value in menuTiposPlatos) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = menuTiposPlatos[value];
     select.add(option);
    }
   }


 function agregarNuevo(){
        let realizarPedidos = document.getElementById('realizarPedidos')
        let newDiv = document.createElement("div");

        newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <div class="realizar-pedidos">
            <select class="form-select" name="tipo-pedido">
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option> </option>
            </select>
            <input id="precio-pedido" readonly placeholder="$" class="form-control">
            <input type="number" id="cant-pedido" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"> 
        </div>
        `

        realizarPedidos.appendChild(newDiv)
        console.log(realizarPedidos)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero un consejo: No uses eventos en línea, del tipo `<body onload="cargarSelect()">` o `<button onclick="funcion()">`, es mejor dejar el HTML legible y sin "distractores", asignando los eventos por medio de Javascript. Esto te va a facilitar el mantenimiento de tus proyectos.

Ahora, para resolver el problema, cuando se cargue la página y se agregue un nuevo select, ejecuta la función y toma el último elemento, que es donde vas a agregar las opciones. Lee los comentarios en el código para entender mejor:

```js
// Llenar primer select al cargar la página
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cargarSelect);

// Asignar evento a botón
document.querySelector('#btn-editar').addEventListener('click', agregarNuevo);

function cargarSelect(){
    let menuTiposPlatos = ["Perros", "Hamburguesas", "Pizzas",  ]
    agregarOpciones("tipo-pedido", menuTiposPlatos);
}

function agregarOpciones(domElement, menuTiposPlatos) {
    // Cargar todos los selects
    let selects = document.getElementsByName(domElement);
    // Seleccionar el último
    let select = selects[selects.length - 1];
    
    for (value in menuTiposPlatos) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = menuTiposPlatos[value];
        select.add(option);
    }
}

function agregarNuevo(){
    let realizarPedidos = document.getElementById('realizarPedidos')
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.innerHTML += `
        <div class="realizar-pedidos">
            <select class="form-select" name="tipo-pedido">
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option> </option>
            </select>
            <input id="precio-pedido" readonly placeholder="$" class="form-control">
            <input type="number" id="cant-pedido" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"> 
        </div>
        `;

    realizarPedidos.appendChild(newDiv);
    // Llenar select agregado
    cargarSelect();
}
```

```html
<h4>REALIZAR PEDIDOS</h4>

<div class="caja-pedidos">
   <div class="label-pedidos">
       <label id="label-tipoP">TIPO</label>
       <label id="label-pedido">PEDIDO</label>
       <label id="label-precio">PRECIO</label>
       <label id="label-cantidad">CANT</label>
   </div>
   <div class="realizar-pedidos" id="realizarPedidos">
       <div class="realizar-pedidos">
           <select id="tipo-pedido" class="form-select" name="tipo-pedido">
               <option></option>
           </select>
           <select id="pedido" class="form-select">
               <option> </option>
           </select>
           <input id="precio-pedido" readonly placeholder="$" class="form-control">
           <input type="number" id="cant-pedido" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"> 
       </div>
   </div>
                   

   <!-- <label id="observacion">OBSERVACIONES</label> -->
<div class="text-area">
<textarea id="obser-pedido" placeholder="OBSERVACIONES" class="form-control"></textarea>
   </div>
       <div class="btn-agregar22">
<button type="button" class="btn-agregar" id="btn-editar"><i class="bi bi-plus-square-fill"></i> Agregar </button>
   </div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu aporte me funcionó muy bien. Gracias por los consejos también.